# Loading multiple fbx

Tags: three.js, fbx

Trying to load multiple fbx in a function, i try different ways to do that in same function, separate functions, same loader, different loaders, etc. but nothing seems to work and the result is same it only loads the first .fbx. 
This is the code that i have:

```
function loadModels(){
   //model1
   var loader1 = new THREE.FBXLoader();
   loader1.load( 'models/model1.fbx', function ( model1 ) {
    scene.add( model1 );
   } );

   //model2
   var loader2 = new THREE.FBXLoader();
   loader2.load( 'models/model2.fbx', function ( model2 ) {
     scene.add( model2 );
   } );

   animate();
}
```

Comment: Please give some more information about your code. Otherwise it will be hard to help you.
Are there any error logs in the console?
Maybe the second model is malformed and results in an error.

Will `model2` load if you load only this model into your scene?

Is `model1` bigger than `model2`? Maybe `model2` is just inside `model1` as you add both models to the same position (0,0,0)

Comment: Hi, there arent console errors the problem seems to be when i try to load more than one fbx. If i load one of them no matter which one it loads ok. There are no problems of size. And also i convert one fbx to obj and load a fbx and a obj and they load ok. That been said i think that is a problem with the fbx loader of three js o the way that im using it.

Comment: Wow I just ran into this last night.. and I think it's a bug in the FBX loader.

Comment: If you pass the extra parameters to the FBXLoader.load .. a "progress()" and an "error()" function, do you find that your error() function is getting called with "FBXTree is not a constructor"?

Comment: And if this does not work you could try out an older version of threejs and update when the bug is fixed https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases

Comment: Also you can open a bug report on the github page https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues this will bring this problem up to attention and hopefully be patched soon

Comment: Yes it seems to be a bug of the FBXLoader. I''ll download an older version and chek if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Yes as you said its a problem on the last release, but the problem is that on older version it doesnt support animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had same issue. Fixed by replacing examples/js/loaders/FBXLoader.js to newer version from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/ (current revision 96)

Problem was that FBXLoader.js had exact same typing "FBXTree" for variable and  function name